# How to move a library from one site to another and keep the ModifedBy field

Tags: powershell

I need to migrate one list from a site to another site, using Gary LaPoint cmdlets i could do something like this:

```
`Get-SPList "http://mysourcedomain.com/sites/ict/list" | Copy-SPList -TargetWeb "http://mydestinationdomain.com/subsitex"
```

This works perfect, but the Modified By field is the person who executed the powershell, not the user It had before the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the drawback of Import API.

> Unfortunately this isn’t something I’m able to fix (at least not
>   easily) as it’s a function of the deployment API from Microsoft. All
>   I’m doing is using their API to do the import. I’d have to either
>   rewrite their import API or write some other routine to attempt to
>   change the modified by user after the import occurs (which can be more
>   problematic that it might seem). You’ll find the same thing will
>   happen if you use the out of the box import command to import an
>   entire web. I’m sorry I’m not being more helpful on this one

I think either you update that field manually( create another column at source list, copy the values from modified by column, once imported then you can copy values from temp column to modified by), or use 3rd party tool.

Comment: if you use the Import-SPWeb instead of the GaryLapointe cmdlet, it has a flag -IncludeUserSecurity, when you export it and when you import it, then it works fine.